Explanation about Frama-C calculus - from ACSL to VCs
I am using Frama-C (mainly WP-plugin) for SW-verification in my masterthesis. I want to understand how Frama-C is working and therefore I wanted to ask, if anyone can explain to me how ACSL annotations are translated into Verification Conditions and then handed to external provers? Does anyone know about a document that lists/explains this calculus of Frama-C?
Thanks a lot for your help!
Best,
Robin
I visited the official website of Frama-C but could not find any explanations. I also looked in the source Code on Gitlab (https://git.frama-c.com/pub/frama-c/-/tree/master/src?ref_type=heads) but I did not realy understand it.

I won't make a full answer, as IMO your question would be more on-topic on https://cs.stackexchange.com/, but Chap. 2 of the WP tutorial gives a brief introduction, and provides the keywords that should allow you to easily find relevant material on the web: "Hoare logic" and "Weakest precondition" (even though Wp mainly uses its dual, i.e. "Strongest postcondition". And of course, there's also the book "Guide to Software Verification with Frama-C" and specifically its chapter 4 on WP (FD: I'm one of the editors)

NB: I took the liberty to edit your tags: "calculus" in "weakest precondition calculus" has nothing to do with differentiation and integration as they are mentioned in the tag's description

There are in fact a lot of different questions in your question. Namely:

how the WP calculus in Frama-C/WP behaves,
how ACSL annotations are compiled,
(conquence of the above) how memory is modeled.

About the WP calculus in Frama-C/WP, several documents can help you. First, the wikipedia page on predicate transformer semantics is pretty clear and gives the basic ideas of the process. As mentioned in the comments under your post, the WP tutorial gives more details (the version on GitHub is more precise than the current stable version of the tutorial). The book "Guide to Software Verification with Frama-C" gives even more details, in particular related to:

the way loops are handled,
the way assignment is handled because of the aliasing problem in C.

In the source code of Frama-C, this topic is covered by two main files in src/plugins/wp:

CfgCalculus that drives the overall WP calculus process and calls,
CfgWP the compiler for each kind of instruction.

To the best of my knowledge, the compilation of ACSL annotations is not described in any existing document. There are two main parts: the first is compiling "simple" terms and predicates, and the second (relying on the first) compiling user defined named predicates and terms. Handling memory aspects in this part is kind of hard since we have to take in account the memory model + the fact that there are labels parameters in ACSL. Thus, there are generally more parameters in the compiled version than the user might expect from what they wrote, because of how WP segment the memory. In the WP directory, it is covered by:

LogicSemantics for basic predicates and terms,
LogicCompiler for user-defined ones.

Finally, the topic on memory is certainly the most complex one. It is described in the book chapter, and also in the WP user manual. The default memory model of WP is the Hoare+Typed model. It has a direct impact on the two above questions since it determines how most terms related to memory will be compiled. For example, an assignment might be modeled by several formulas and not only one.
